# How to make JS AJAX / FLASK render_template works WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am building mechanism which sends:

1. variable from JS AJAX to FLASK - succeeded!
2. routing to another page (/ajax) - without success yet..

I know there are literally hundreds of questions/answers regarding such a mechanism (2), BUT I couldn't find even one regarding routing FLASK from AJAX without jQuery - just pure js. I really need help or just suggestion. I am stuck.

What I tried so far:

**js**

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
           req.onreadystatechange = function()
           {
               if (req.readyState == 4)
               {
                   if (req.status != 200)
                   {
                    console.log('error AJAX link sends to FLASK')
                    }
                   else
                   {
                      link
                      user_id = document.querySelector('.logo_fi').innerHTML
                    }
                  }
                }
                req.open('POST', '/ajax', true)
                req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
                user_id = document.querySelector('.logo_fi').innerHTML
                var send = {user_id: user_id, link : link};
                req.send(JSON.stringify(send))
                req.open('GET', '/ajax', true)
                return false
```

**py**

```
@app.route('/ajax', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def ajax_request():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('request received') 
        json_data = request.json
        a = json_data
        a2 = a['link'];
        a1 = a['user_id'];
        start = '<a href="../">'
        end = '<br> LINK.COM</a>'
        a3 = a1[a1.find(start)+len(start):a1.rfind(end)]
        connection = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        link_id = a2
        user_id = a3
        params = deleted(id=None, user_id=user_id, link_id=link_id)
        db.session.add(params)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("ajax.html")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**

You send request to the server (post or get) from the client with javascript.

you can use the new XMLHttpRequest object or you can also use jquery / fetch or any other library it does not matter.

it's all under the javascript / browser rules.

**Second**

the server get your request and answer with a status code.

Flask render_template() will return 200 and the browser will not be redirected.

Flask redirect() will return 302 and the browser will probably follow.

**Third**

If you use render_template() you will need to use windows.location.href.

**Note - About redirect loop**

You try to send a request to "/ajax" and also redirect to "/ajax".

You should probably redirect the user to other url when the response arrive.

Something like "/home".

**Note - About Redirect In General And Javascript**

Sending ajax request from the client does not mean that the browser will redirect the user after the response arrive.

In your case you use render_template() which will return status code 200.

You probably need to use redirect() which will return status code 302 or 301.

If the server sends a redirect (aka a 302 response plus a Location: header) the browser will probably automatically redirect. But it's up to the browser to honor the redirect.

But anyway redirect using javascript might not always work.

**Note - About Javascript in general**

you try to send a get request after post request. If your get request depends on the the post request you need to use a promise or callback. But in your situation i think you can just drop the second get request.

### Solution 1: using flask redirect()

This is one solution for your question.

You need to send a post request to the server.

The server will answer with 302. (using Flask redirect()).

The browser will probably follow the redirect.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var user_id = document.querySelector('.logo_fi').innerHTML;
var link = null;
var url = "/ajax";
var send = {user_id: user_id, link : link}

req.open("POST", url, true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
req.send(JSON.stringify(send));
```

```
@app.route('/ajax', methods = ['POST'])
def ajax_request():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = request.json
        a = json_data
        a2 = a['link'];
        a1 = a['user_id'];
        start = '<a href="../">'
        end = '<br> LINK.COM</a>'
        a3 = a1[a1.find(start)+len(start):a1.rfind(end)]
        connection = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        link_id = a2
        user_id = a3
        params = deleted(id=None, user_id=user_id, link_id=link_id)
        db.session.add(params)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect("/home", code=302)
```

### Solution 2: using flask render_template()

You can use flask render_template().

You need to send a post request to the server.

The server will answer with 200. (using Flask render_template()).

The browser will not follow.

you will use windows.locarion.href on the client.

you can also use window.location.replace.

replace() means it won't create an entry in your browser's history.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var user_id = document.querySelector('.logo_fi').innerHTML;
var link = null;
var url = "/ajax";
var send = {user_id: user_id, link : link}

req.open("POST", url, true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(req.readyState == 4){
  if(req.status == 200){
   windows.locarion.href = "/home"
  }
 }
}
req.send(JSON.stringify(send));
```

```
@app.route('/ajax', methods = ['POST'])
def ajax_request():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = request.json
        a = json_data
        a2 = a['link'];
        a1 = a['user_id'];
        start = '<a href="../">'
        end = '<br> LINK.COM</a>'
        a3 = a1[a1.find(start)+len(start):a1.rfind(end)]
        connection = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        link_id = a2
        user_id = a3
        params = deleted(id=None, user_id=user_id, link_id=link_id)
        db.session.add(params)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("ajax.html")
```

### Solution 3: using flask jsonify()

You can also use jsonify()

In this case use solution number 2

replace render_template("ajax.html")

with jsonify()

### Some resources

Flask Render Template

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Flask Redirect

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.redirect

Flask jsonify

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify

Flask response general

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#about-responses

Comment: Hi Naor, your answer is really exhaustive and it helped me to better understand this case. Thank you for your time and you support! I really appreciate it. I implemented solution 2 and it works really good!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `window.location.href =  "/<url>"` after `req.send(JSON.stringify(send))` to route to another page. This will send a GET request to flask on said *url* where you can return `render_template("ajax.html")`

Comment: Hi Antonio2924, thanks for your help.You answer is correct and it works! Thanks!!!